# Playwright: how to test the order in which elements load

Tags: python, playwright-python, playwright-test

I keep getting `TimeoutError` with `page.wait_for_selector('selector')`. The method `page.wait_for_load_state()` doesn't help either so I am using `time.sleep()` as an alternative. Is there a way to study which elements of page load and in what order. Is there a method for that?

Comment: P.S I am a noob. Learning Python & Playwright

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I recommend using page.wait_for_timeout() instead of time.sleep(), second, make sure your selector is correct, the default timeout time is 30 seconds, enough for elements to appear! Use headless=False to monitor if the element is showing.